# POST 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a registration form using Fetch API. The formdata is sent to the database but I still get an error in devtools 'POST http://localhost/sem2/UX2/ws.php?request=registration 401 (Unauthorized)'. Tried a few different headers but nothing has worked so far.
This is my JS code -

```
document.querySelector('#regoform').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = document.querySelector('#regoform');
  const data = new URLSearchParams();
  for(const p of new FormData(form)) {
      data.append(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]);
  }

  fetch('./ws.php?request=registration', {

      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      mode: 'cors'

  }) 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))     
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

});
```

and this is my php file

```
            if (isset($_GET['request'])){
            switch($_GET['request']) {
                case 'registration':
                    $fName = $_POST['fName'];
                    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
                    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
                    $age = $_POST['age'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $result = $dbobj->newUser($fName, $surname, $gender, $age, $email, $password);
                    break;
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shared sends authentication data or throws a 401 status code. Whatever server-side access control you've implemented, you aren't providing the required credentials.

Comment: thanks alvaro, what would I have to add in order to make it work?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. If you don't care about authorisation, you need to **remove** stuff. It isn't the default; it only happens because you're added code to ask for it.

Comment: ok I understand, thanks I think that will help